# pass parameter from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

how to pass a parameter from jsp to servlet using form which is not belong to any field of form without using session.i think code may be look like below example but doesn't work for me.plz help me.

in index.jsp:-

```
<form method="Post" action="servlet">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
          <% 
              int z=1;
              request.setAttribute("product_no", z);%>
        <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

in servlet.java:-

```
 int x=Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("product_no").toString());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your form needs to be submitted, e.g. have a submit button. And you need to have your parameter as an input.  Calling `request.setAttribute` inside the form doesn't do anything. Setting a request attribute is for when you are going to use a dispatcher to forward the request, not when you are using a form.

```
<% int z=1; %>
<form method="Post" action="servlet">
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <input type="password" name="password" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_no" value="<%=z%>" />
        <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: but if i wants to pass a parameter when form is submitted instead of using any input field. how should i do this?

Comment: @user3751576, That question doesn't make sense to me. What are you trying to ask? What's the real goal here?

Comment: i get it. thnx. so, to pass a value through a form we have to use an input field. i think now i am right.

Answer (score 8):

You can receive the parameters you submit in the form with the method:

```
request.getParameter("fieldname");
```

For intance, your servlet could get all the fields:

```
 @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

                            String username= request.getParameter("username");
                            String password= request.getParameter("password");

            }
}
```

You can also send parameters from a link, e.g:

```
<a href="Servlet?nameOfParameter=valueOFparameter">
```